# jQuery Flot charting library in Android WebView doesn't work correctly

Tags: android-fragments, android-webview, flot

I'm trying to implement Flot charts in my Android app using `WebView`. Basically I have a `Fragment` which contains a `WebView`. I also have a refresh button which refreshes the `Fragment` (and the WebView thus) by retrieving new data from a web service and putting them in the chart.

The problem I'm having is that the `WebView` at first launch (when the fragment is created) either doesn't show the chart or it shows a smaller chart (i.e. half screen).
When I click refresh the chart shows fine without any problem, so the problem is only when the fragment is first created.

What I do on `onCreateView` is calling this:

```
chartWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

And I have an `AsyncTask` which retrieves the data from the server, and then calls javascript on the WebView like this:

```
chartWebView.loadUrl("javascript:displayChart(" + data + ")");
```

I also have overrided the `onResume` method where I call the `refresh()` function.

The `refresh()` method basically executes the `AsyncTask` to reload the data, which at `onPostExecute(...)` calls the javascript on the WebView.

Any hints?

Comment: Do you set the placeholder `div` for the flot graph to a fixed width and height before you draw the graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess but...

`webView.loadUrl()` is asynchronous.  I think your first `AsyncTask` executes before the `loadUrl` completes.  I'd recommend to do your initial `displayChart` in an [onPageFinished](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I believe this is the problem. As I tested and saw that the javascript didn't get executed at all. I'll give it a try right now

Comment: it worked out, thanks! Although the "small chart" problem was still occurring, I sorted that out as the WebView seemed to resize itself to fit screen after some time, but $(window).resize() fixed it.